# Capture value from URL string with php

Tags: php, url, parameters, capture

I need to extract a variable's value from a string, which happens to be a URL.  The string/url is loaded as part of a separate php query, not the url in the browser.

The url's will look like:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=334:golfeq&id=2773:xcelsiors&Itemid=44
```

How can I always find & capture the value of the id which in this example is 2773?

I read several examples already, but what I've tried captures the id value of the current page which is being viewed in the browser, and not the URL string.

Thanks

Comment: The value of id is not "2773" but "2773:xcelsiors".

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a combination or [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) (which will isolate the query string for you) and [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) (which will parse the variables and put them into an array).

For example:

```
$url = 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=334:golfeq&id=2773:xcelsiors&Itemid=44';

// This parses the url for the query string, and parses the vars from that
// into the array $vars (which is created on the spot).
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $vars);

print_r($vars); // see what's in there

// Parse the value "2773:xcelsiors" to isolate the number
$id = reset(explode(':', $vars['id']));

// This will also work:
$id = intval($vars['id']);

echo "The id is $id\n";
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/DTZr5)**.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think I'm seeing the symptoms of why this is not working for me.  When i perform the print_r($vars), instead of getting for example [catid] => 334:golfeq  it's showing [amp;catid] => 334   So I think there's some problem processing the "&".  Any idea how I can address that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: The string is not the site's URL, hence the values won't be in the `$_GET` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parse_url to parse URLs!

But you can use, to extract directly the numbers of ID variable:

```
$url = 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=334:golfeq&id=2773:xcelsiors&Itemid=44';
$id = preg_replace("/^.*[&?]id=([0-9]+).*$/",'$1',$url);
echo $id;
```